# Parse large JSON file in Python

Tags: python, json

I'm trying to parse a really large JSON file in Python.
The file has 6523440 lines but is broken into a lot of JSON objects.

The structure looks like this:

```
[
  {
    "projects": [
     ...
    ]
  }
]
[
  {
    "projects": [
     ...
    ]
  }
]
....
....
....
```

and it goes on and on...

Every time I try to load it using json.load() I get an error

```
ValueError: Extra data: line 2247 column 1 - line 6523440 column 1 (char 101207 - 295464118)
```

On the line where the first object ends and the second one starts.
Is there a way to load them separately or anything similar?

Comment: I think you would have to parse the file yourself and split it into separate objects *before* passing it to `json.load` - it doesn't handle reading a bit and passing it back like e.g. `pickle`, AFAIK.

Comment: That structure suggests multiple arrays of one object

Comment: It is. 2900 of them to be precise

Comment: It sounds like your file is missing a comma at the end of the previous line (or something similar).

Comment: It's erroring because that's not valid JSON. You need to separate the elements with commas in the right places.

Comment: Try pasting the contents of the file into an online JSON validator.

Answer (score 2):

You can try using a streaming json library like [ijson](https://github.com/isagalaev/ijson):

> Sometimes when dealing with a particularly large JSON payload it may
>   worth to not even construct individual Python objects and react on
>   individual events immediately producing some result

Answer (score 0):

Try using `json.JSONDecoder.raw_decode`. It still requires you to have the entire document in memory, but allows you to iteratively decode many objects from one string.

```
import re
import json

document = """
[
    1,
    2,
    3
]
{
    "a": 1,
    "b": 2,
    "c": 3
}
"""

not_whitespace = re.compile(r"\S")

decoder = json.JSONDecoder()

items = []
index = 0
while True:
    match = not_whitespace.search(document, index)
    if not match:
        break

    item, index = decoder.raw_decode(document, match.start())
    items.append(item)

print(items)
```